# Operator norm and L infinity norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$g \in L^\infty[0,1]$, $F: L^1[0,1] \to R$ by $F(f) = \int_{[0,1]}fg$, show that $\lVert F\rVert = \lVert g \rVert_\infty$.

I can prove that $\lVert F\rVert \le \lVert g \rVert_\infty$ simply by $\int \lvert fg \rvert \le \lVert g \rVert_\infty \int \lvert f \rvert $. Now it remains to find an $f$, such that $\lVert f \rVert_1 = 1$ and $\lvert F(f) \rvert =  \lVert g \rVert_\infty$. I just cannot come up with such a case, can someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can find such an $f $. But you can do the following. Given $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a measurable set $E $ where $|g|>\|g\|_\infty-\varepsilon  $. Let $f=\frac h{m (E)}\,1_E $, where $|h|=1$ and $hg=|g|$; then
$$
\int fg=\frac1 {m (E)}\int_E|g|>\|g\|_\infty-\varepsilon .
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $g\in L^q$ and $F:L^p[0,1]\to\mathbb{K}$ (such that $1/p+1/q=1$ and $p\in(1,\infty)$) there is possible function to show the claim:

$$f=\frac{\overline{g}}{|g|}\left(\frac{|g|}{\Vert g\Vert_q}\right)^{\frac{q}{p}}$$

One has to modify this function for the case $q=\infty$.

Comment: then $\lvert F(f) \rvert = \lVert g \rVert_\infty$, but $\int \rvert f \rvert > 1 $, seems not correct. Did I do it wrong?